# compgen on zsh returns a different result than on bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, autocomplete

I am trying to make bash completions work properly in zsh.

I am aware of the need to load these in `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
autoload -Uz +X compinit && compinit
autoload -Uz +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
```

One thing I observed, is that the `compgen` command behaves differently in zsh.

```bsh
# In bash (as expected):
$ compgen -W "one two three" -- "t"
two
three

# In zsh ("one" is not expected to be listed)
$ compgen -W "one two three" -- "t"
one
two
three
```

Despite that, completions still work - but I am trying to understand why these are different, and perhaps if there is a different compgen syntax that returns the same results in both shells.